# Google Assistant Created in DialogFlow Endpoint Changes

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, assistant

I have created a Google Home app in DialogFlow and have since had the app published by Google.  I am assuming that I can change the fulfillment endpoint address in Dialogflow and this won't affect my live app - my assumption being that a packaged version of the app together with the endpoint at submission time is what is running on the Google Assistant.

Does anybody know if this assumption is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this assumption is **not** correct.

By default, changing the fulfillment URL in your Dialogflow project will change it for the live Action.

Although there is some information that is generated when you release an Action built with Dialogflow (the Intents and Entities, for example, get turned into entries for the Assistant), the fulfillment URL is not one of them. The Assistant sends it to a special URL on Dialogflow's servers, and Dialogflow then sends it to the URL you've specified.

*However*, you can look into the Dialogflow Beta feature that supports [versions and environments](https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/versions-environments) to see if that will do what you want.

Comment: great stuff, thanks for the clarification. I have looked at the environment feature but wrongly assumed that you were creating a full 'package' for google actions.  I expected the endpoint (in DialogFlow) to be relevant for say a website integration but was not sure about Google Assistant.  cheers